# Need help referencing PECL OAuth from a Laravel 5 app

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 application where I am building a custom OAuth interface.  Everything is working well, but I cannot figure out how to reference the PECL OAuth package which is installed on the server.  I'm sure its something pretty simple, but I can't figure it out and Google has oddly not been very helpful.

I have this line of code:

```
$oauth = new OAuth($ConsumerKey, $ConsumerSecret);
```

When outside of Laravel, it works perfectly, referencing the PHP package.  But from within Laravel, it cannot find the class - because its not part of the application.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the exact error PHP is sending your way?  I ask because `pecl` extensions make functions and classes available on a PHP level -- it shouldn't matter what userland level framework (Laravel, Symfony, etc.) you're using -- so long as the same PHP binary/web-server-extension is used, you'll have access to the `pecl` provided functions and classes.

My guess if you're trying to use the **global** class `OAuth` from within a namespaced file.

```
namespace App\Some\Namespace;
//...
$object = new OAuth;
```

When you do this, you're telling PHP you want the class `OAuth` in the **same namespace**.  i.e., the class with the full name `App\Some\Namespace\OAuth`.  To tell PHP you want the global level class `OAuth`, either refer to the class name with a namespace prefix character

```
$object = new \OAuth;
```

or import the global `OAuth` class with the `use` statement.

```
namespace App\Some\Namespace;
use OAuth;   //confusingly, the `use` statement assumes a global namespace, no prefix needed
//...
$object = new OAuth;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!! Thank you.  I did not understand the global namespacing thing, and now I do.  I added the use statement as just "use OAuth" and it works.  Perfect!